# How do you check for a scalar in R?

Tags: r

I am interested identifying numeric scalars like:

```
doub <- 3.14
intg <- 8L
```

I know that these are treated as length one vectors. Thus, for any R object `x`, is `is.vector(x) && length(x) == 1` the right way to check whether `x` is a scalar? `length(x) == 1` by itself is not sufficient as it returns a true, when it should return false, for a data frame with one column or a list with one element.

Is there a reason why there is no such function `is.scalar` implemented in base `R`? For some reason the two I could find in other functions fail for the data frame case mentioned previously, these are:

```
assertthat::is.scalar(data.frame(a = 1:2))
lambda.tools::is.scalar(data.frame(a = 1:2))
```

Why are the results of these two function calls different to my understanding (and definition) of how a `is.scalar` function should work?

Comment: You probably want `is.atomic` instead of `is.vector`.

Comment: what's the difference between the two?

Comment: See `?is.atomic`: "It is common to call the atomic types ‘atomic vectors’, but note that `is.vector` imposes further restrictions: an object can be atomic but not a vector (in that sense)."

Comment: What do you want returned for `factor(1)`?

Comment: @thelatemail I guess I would like it to return true?

Comment: [`purrr` has some `is_scalar_*` functions](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/purrr/versions/0.2.1/topics/scalar-type-predicates) that may be useful.

Comment: I think the way these functions are implemented in `purrr` is what I am looking for, thanks.

Comment: fwiw, purrr basically seems to implement exactly what was suggested below: https://github.com/hadley/purrr/blob/dc60831d86fc861c3caa41d8205d9cb1aa31ec1d/R/objects.R

Comment: Yes it does @MichaelChirico, however, what is different for me is the distinction `purrr` makes between the different type of scalars. Based on the comments and answers it seems like everyone has a different idea of what a scalar is.

Comment: not gainsaying, just pointing out for future readers that purrr is not reinventing the wheel :)

Comment: Because R is a vectorized language, meaning it was designed to try generalize over vectors as much as possible. Hence a scalar is just a vector of length as (as you already noticed). To my understanding- this is more of a philosophical question. Similarly to why R isn't modifying objects in place or why dplyr tibble-whatevers with one column still remain tibble-whatevers rather just a vector (like in base R).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think `is.atomic` suits your needs.

For why `is.vector` is probably incompatible, see, e.g.:

```
is.atomic(list(1))
# [1] FALSE

is.vector(list(1))
# [1] TRUE
```

On your objects:

```
is.scalar <- function(x) is.atomic(x) && length(x) == 1L

is.scalar(doub)
# [1] TRUE

is.scalar(intg)
# [1] TRUE

is.scalar(c(doub, intg))
# [1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 9):

Building on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38088500/2761575) by @MichaelChirico, there are a couple of other things that `is.scalar()` should check for.

Firstly, complex numbers are not usually regarded as scalars (although I think this usage may vary between disciplines).

```
comp <- 2+3i
is.scalar <- function(x) is.atomic(x) && length(x) == 1L
is.scalar(comp)
# TRUE
```

so we should also check for complex numbers. The simple, but naive, way to do this is to use `is.complex`

```
is.scalar <- function(x) is.atomic(x) && length(x) == 1L && !is.complex(x) 
is.scalar(comp)
# FALSE
```

Unfortunately, this is not quite right, because `is.complex` just tests whether the class is `"complex"`. But real numbers can have class=complex if their imaginary component is zero.

```
is.complex(2+0i)
# [1] TRUE
```

So to test for real numbers we are better off to check that the imaginary component is zero using `Im(x)==0`. So, this leads us to a test for scalars that look like this

```
is.scalar <- function(x) is.atomic(x) && length(x) == 1L && Im(x)==0
```

More trivially, characters ought also be eliminated

```
is.scalar("x")
# TRUE
is.scalar <- function(x) is.atomic(x) && length(x) == 1L && !is.character(x) && Im(x)==0
is.scalar("x")
# FALSE
```

Note that we test for `is.character(x)` before `Im(x)==0` so that lazy evaluation ensures that the function never tries to find the imaginary component of a character, which would throw an error.

Comment: So why not simply use `is.scalar <- function (x) length(x) == 1L && is.vector(x, mode = "numeric")` ?

Comment: @Wastl It depends on your purpose and exaclty what you want to test for, but using your definition `is.scalar(x)` would fail for e.g. `x=1+0i`, `x=NA`, and `x=1; attr(x, 'foo') = 1`

Answer (score -1):

A complex number of course is a scalar, it's a number.
So `is.scalar <- function(x) is.atomic(x) && length(x) == 1L` is sufficient, i guess.

Comment: A complex number is in fact a two dimensional vector, not a scalar.

Comment: @Dmytro Dadyja, in linear algebra a vector space is defined over a field F, and scalar multiplication is when you multiply a vector (an element of the set of vectors) by a scalar (an element of the field). The field can be the set of complex numbers, meaning that the scalars are complex numbers.