# Vector vs. List vs. Single-row matrix vs. Single-column matrix with R

Tags: r, matrix, vector

When entering this in the R console:

```
1 + 2
```

we get, as an answer:

```
[1] 3
```

Does the leading `[1]` mean *"The output is a matrix, and the elements in the first line of this matrix are: 3"* ?

More generally, are these objects a vector, a list, a single-row matrix or a single-column matrix?

- `1 + 2` (i.e. `3`, i.e. just a number)
- `c(1,-2,3,14)`
- `A = matrix(c(1,-2,3,14),2,2)`
  `A[1,]`: this is the first line of the matrix. Is it a (1, 2) single-row matrix or just a vector or a list?
- `A[,2]`: this is the second column of the matrix. Is it a (2, 1) single-column matrix or just a vector or a list?

I've already read the documentation a few times, but I was wondering if there exists a rule of thumb to remember this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, for checking the data types in R, you can use several functions contained in the `base` package.

Now, focusing on your explicit questions:

```
> is.vector(1 + 2)
[1] TRUE
> is.atomic(1 + 2)
[1] TRUE
> length(1 + 2)
[1] 1
```

Consequently, the result is stored in a vector of length 1.

```
> is.vector(c(1,-2,3,14))
[1] TRUE
> is.atomic(c(1,-2,3,14))
[1] TRUE
```

As `c(...)` initializes a vector object, obviously the data type is a vector.

```
> is.matrix(A)
[1] TRUE
> is.vector(A)
[1] FALSE
> is.atomic(A)
[1] TRUE
> is.vector(A[1, ])
[1] TRUE
> is.atomic(A[1, ])
[1] TRUE
> is.matrix(A[1, ])
[1] FALSE
> is.vector(A[, 2])
[1] TRUE
> is.atomic(A[, 2])
[1] TRUE
> is.matrix(A[, 2])
[1] FALSE
```

And finally, subsetting a matrix row-wise or column-wise returns also a vector and not a matrix.

<s>For checking for a scalar, please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088392/how-do-you-check-for-a-scalar-in-r).</s>

Edit:

As mentioned by [@Rich Scriven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3063910/rich-scriven), there are two types of vectors in R: **atomic** and **generic** vectors. Indeed, the function `is.vector(x)` used in above examples returns `TRUE` for lists as well. Besides that, `is.atomic(x)` checks for **atomic** vectors which contain data of one primitive data type (logical, integer, real, complex, character, or raw) only. Additionally, I have added the respective `is.atomic(x)` function calls in above examples as well.

Comment: `is.vector` is not useful here because lists are also vectors.  `is.vector(list(1 + 2))` is also true.  I think `is.atomic` is more appropriate, and OP should learn the difference between atomic and list vectors.

Comment: Secondly, there is no such thing as a scalar in R.  It is simply a length 1 atomic vector.

Comment: @RichScriven Just to be sure to understand, can you give an example of a list which is not a vector, and vice-versa? For example, are `c(1,2,3,4)` and `1:10` lists or vectors?

Comment: @taupe117 those are both atomic vectors. Try `list(c(1,2,3),c(1,2))`. Then see what happens when you `unlist()` that `list`.